# Pointers to C functions from Go causing unexpected fault address

Tags: c, go, pointers

I am trying to use functions from a 3rd party C SDK in my GoLang code.

I have already successfully accomplished exactly what I need to do in C++ (for the same library), as so:

```cpp
mLibrary = LoadLibraryW( L"SDK-Win64-Shipping" );
typedef EResult ( *InitFunc )( InitializeOptions* );
InitializeOptions initOpts = {
        API_LATEST,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        "Name",
        "Version 1.2.3.4",
        nullptr,
    };
InitFunc mInitFunc = nullptr;                                                
mInitFunc = reinterpret_cast<InitFunc>( GetProcAddress( mLibrary, CCP_STRINGIZE( Initialize ) ) ); 
EResult result = mInitFunc( &initOpts );
```

trying to recreate the same steps in Golang gives me this:

```golang
type InitFunc func(*InitializeOptions) eResult

type InitializeOptions struct {
    ApiVersion int32
    AllocateMemoryFunction unsafe.Pointer
    ReallocateMemoryFunction unsafe.Pointer
    ReleaseMemoryFunction unsafe.Pointer
    ProductName           string
    ProductVersion        string
    Reserved              unsafe.Pointer
}

func main() {
    mLibrary, err := GetHandle("SDK-Linux-Shipping.so") 

    initOpts := InitializeOptions{API_LATEST, nil, nil,
        nil, "Name",
        "Version 1.2.3.4", nil}

    sym := C.CString("Initialize")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(sym))
    C.dlerror()
    p := C.dlsym(mLibrary.Handle, sym)
    mInitFunc := *(*InitFunc)(unsafe.Pointer(&p))

    ret := mInitFunc(&initOpts) //CRASH HERE
}
```

The last line crashes the program with this error:

```
unexpected fault address 0x0
fatal error: fault
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x80 addr=0x0 pc=0x48f8c3]

goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime.throw({0x4a9327?, 0xc000018030?})
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:992 +0x71 fp=0xc0000c1d40 sp=0xc0000c1d10 pc=0x432931
runtime.sigpanic()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:825 +0x305 fp=0xc0000c1d90 sp=0xc0000c1d40 pc=0x4464a5
main.main()
    /tmp/871cf058-c0e6-499b-8627-cf01aa55d09d/main.go:151 +0x383 fp=0xc0000c1f80 sp=0xc0000c1d90 pc=0x48f8c3
runtime.main()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250 +0x212 fp=0xc0000c1fe0 sp=0xc0000c1f80 pc=0x435052
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571 +0x1 fp=0xc0000c1fe8 sp=0xc0000c1fe0 pc=0x45dce1
```

I know for sure that

1. no errors are thrown at ay point preceding this
2. mLibrary and mInitFunc are not nil
3. The code compiles

Why am I seeing this error message?

Comment: That `string` in the definition of your Go `struct` is almost certainly incorrect: in Go, a string is a `struct` containing a pointer to the memory block containing the string's data and an integer containing the length of that memory block. In C++ `std::string` is the value of a class which is (usually) a disguised pointer. These types do not match.

Comment: I could guess, that you need to use `*C.char` in that definition instead, and use `C.CString` to generate these values from your Go `string`s. Please make sure you've completely read [the docs on `cgo`](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) before using it.

Comment: …to better understand the issue, your `InitializeOptions` as defined in your Go code has layout different from the matching type as seen on the C++ side. You did not show its definition from there but I'd expect it to have `*char` (may be with some `const`s spilled around) or maybe `std::string`. The latter is less likely as we're probably witnessing working with a library with the C-compatible API—as there's a `LoadLibraryW` call…

Comment: Another possible problem is `p := C.dlsym(mLibrary.Handle, sym); mInitFunc := *(*InitFunc)(unsafe.Pointer(&p)); ret := mInitFunc(&initOpts)` sequence: I'd expect `C.dlsym` to return the address of the function. But you're taking an address of the variable which received that value—`p`, and use it to call a function. Another problem is that you don't call `C.dlerror` again after the call to `C.dlsym`, and do not check whether it returned a non-`NULL` result. That is, looks like you did not bother to read the `dlsym(3)` manual page; please do.